# Merging pandas columns (one-to-many)

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am new to Python’s Pandas. I want to combine several Excel sheets by a common ID. Besides, there it is a one-to-many relationship.

Here are the inputs:

**df1**:

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 3763058 | Andi |
| 3763077 | Mark |

**df2**:

| ID | Tag |
| --- | --- |
| 3763058 | item1 |
| 3763058 | item2 |
| 3763058 | item3 |
| 3763077 | item4 |
| 3763077 | item5 |
| 3763077 | item6 |

I would now like to merge the two pandas data frames df1 and df2 into the following output (the column tag is merged in a single column per ID):

| ID | Name | Tag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3763058 | Andi | item1, item2, item3 |
| 3763077 | Mark | item4, item5, item6 |

Could anybody please help me with this?

Cheers,
Andi

Answer (score 17):

You can use first [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `join`:

```
df2 = df2.groupby('ID')['Tag'].apply(', '.join).reset_index()
print (df2)
        ID                     Tag
0  3763058     item1, item2, item3
1  3763077  item_4, item_5, item_6
```

Then is possible use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html), especially if `df1` has more columns:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='ID', how='left')
print (df)
        ID  Name                     Tag
0  3763058  Andi     item1, item2, item3
1  3763077  Mark  item_4, item_5, item_6
```

Solution with [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html), if need add only one column:

```
df2 = df2.groupby('ID')['Tag'].apply(', '.join).reset_index()
df2['Name'] = df2['ID'].map(df1.set_index('ID')['Name'])
print (df2)
        ID                     Tag  Name
0  3763058     item1, item2, item3  Andi
1  3763077  item_4, item_5, item_6  Mark
```

If important position of `Name` column use [`insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html):

```
df2 = df2.groupby('ID')['Tag'].apply(', '.join).reset_index()
df2.insert(1, 'Name', df2['ID'].map(df1.set_index('ID')['Name']))
print (df2)
        ID  Name                     Tag
0  3763058  Andi     item1, item2, item3
1  3763077  Mark  item_4, item_5, item_6
```